# How to add default throttled API key for unauthenticated API Gateway requests to prevent abuse?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'd like to add a default throttled API key for unauthenticated requests to prevent abuse.

How would I do this in API Gateway?

**EDIT**

To make it clearer what I need, how do I transform a request in API Gateway? Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to transform a request *before* the API key validation/throttling step.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot I haven't found a way yet, don't think it's possible either

Comment: Is this an API that supports both authenticated and unauthenticated access to the same resources?  I assume you see that you can throttle any one resource+method independently.  Without just a bit more info on your intentions, it's hard to suggest alternatives or workarounds that might be of interest.

Comment: The idea is to allow unauthenticated access for users to test the service with no sign up, but to limit the number and/or throttle the requests that can be made while unauthenticated

Comment: Atm I'm considering storing a count of API calls per IP in dynamodb in a custom authorizer

Answer (score 1):

I would say using [Cognito](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html) is the best way of authorizing API gateway.

If you want a default API key then you can go for custom API gateway authorizer. Please have a look on official documentation for the same [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-custom-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway/)

Comment: what does cognito offer? Can it generate API keys for users on signup? Handle billing? Thanks for the answer, looking into a custom authorizer

Comment: Amazon Cognito is a service that you can use to create unique identities for your users, authenticate these identities with identity providers, and save mobile user data in the AWS Cloud. So each user will have their on identification. I have edited question with Cognito documentation

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the API Key in the Server Side of your application and shouldn't expose it to the Client Side (Although API Key is not considered as a security token, it can be used by malicious party to call your API).

There are couple of options you have based on the nature of your application consuming the API.

- If it is a single page web application where front-end is hosted in S3, you can use AWS CloudFront to store the API Key in headers and forward it to the API Gateway, while also serving the frontend through the same CloudFront distribution. This will also remove the cross origin resource sharing problem between your web application and API Gateway.
- If you have a web server, you can store the API Key at Web Server and use to proxy request to the API Gateway while setting the API Key header value.

Note: Don't use API Key for authentication which is not recommended.

Comment: The API is exposed via API Gateway, not a webserver or a hosted webpage

Comment: How do you consume the API? from web client or from a web server?

Comment: That depends on however the client decides to access it, I'm not consuming the API myself only providing it

Comment: When you provide the API, API Key validation is handled by the API Gateway when you activate it (Can make it mandatory)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would solve it.

Create **Usage Plan** with the throttle, burst and max limit on the request allowed.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html#createUsagePlan-property

**API Key:**

Create API Key **(createApiKey)** and associate it **(createUsagePlanKey)** with Usage Plan already defined. That will allow the limit defined for the requests received.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html#createApiKey-property

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html#createUsagePlanKey-property

Have a separate lambda to monitor the Generated API-Keys and cleanup once it is expired, so you will not flood API-Gateway with unused keys.

If you take it to CloudFront, you can create Self Signed URL, that will be valid for a given period of time. After that time limit URL will be invalid. This is to keep yourself time-limited for the user, so within the given timelimit, what resource they can access.

One more usecase, we worked on, you can authenticate the user only on certain urls with custom Authorizer. Any other urls that get invokes, will return unauthorized without any additional code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is a good answer as it addresses the OP's specific needs.